# Pyspark automatically rename repeated columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns, rename

I want to automatically rename repeated columns of a df. For example:

```python
df 
Out[4]: DataFrame[norep1: string, num1: string, num1: bigint, norep2: bigint, num1: bigint, norep3: bigint]
```

Apply some function to end with a df like:

```python
f_rename_repcol(df) 
Out[4]: DataFrame[norep1: string, num1_1: string, num1_2: bigint, norep2: bigint, num1_3: bigint, norep3: bigint]
```

I've already create my own function, and works, but I'm sure there is a shorter and better way of doing it:

```python
def f_df_col_renombra_rep(df):
    from collections import Counter
    from itertools import chain
    import pandas as pd

    columnas_original = np.array(df.columns)
    d1 = Counter(df.columns)
    i_corrige = [a>1 for a in dict(d1.items()).values()]
    var_corrige = np.array(dict(d1.items()).keys())[i_corrige]
    var_corrige_2 = [a for a in columnas_original if a in var_corrige]
    columnas_nuevas = []
    for var in var_corrige:
        aux_corr = [a for a in var_corrige_2 if a in var]
        i=0
        columnas_nuevas_aux=[]
        for valor in aux_corr:
            i+=1
            nombre_nuevo = valor +"_"+ str(i)
            columnas_nuevas_aux.append(nombre_nuevo)
        columnas_nuevas.append(columnas_nuevas_aux)
    columnas_nuevas=list(chain.from_iterable(columnas_nuevas))
    indice_cambio = pd.Series(columnas_original).isin(var_corrige)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    colsalida = [None]*len(df.columns)
    for col in df.columns:
        if indice_cambio[i] == True:
            colsalida[i] = columnas_nuevas[j]
            j += 1
        else:
            colsalida[i] = col
            # no cambio el nombre
        i += 1

    df_out = df.toDF(*(colsalida))

    return  df_out
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the renaming function here to suit your need, but broadly I find this as the best way to rename all the duplicates columns

```
old_col=df.schema.names
running_list=[]
new_col=[]
i=0
for column in old_col:
    if(column in running_list):
        new_col.append(column+"_"+str(i))
        i=i+1
    else:
        new_col.append(column)
        running_list.append(column)
print(new_col)
```

This the conversion I do, the suffix assigned to the duplicate columns is not that of difference until the name(prefix) remains the same & I can save the file.

To update the columns you can simply run:

```
df=df.toDF(*new_col)
```

This should update the column names and remove all the duplicates

If you want to keep the numbering as _1,_2,_3:
You can use a dictionary and try and except block,

```
dict={}
for column in old_col:
    try:
        i=dict[column]+1
        new_col.append(column+"_"+str(i))
        dict[column]=i
    except:
        dict[column]=1
        new_col.append(column+"_"+str(1)
print(new_col)
```

Comment: I've found this works fine with most df, but I've got these two cases in which it doesn't: i) if there are two columns which are same but one of them is upper caps and the other lower (solved) ii) when the column has only numbers

Comment: Just adding .upper() solves the first problem:


 `def f_df_col_renombra_rep(df):
    '''Funcion que, dado un df devuelve otro cambiando nombres a las columnas con nombres repetidos'''
    old_col = [a.upper() for a in df.schema.names]
    running_list = []
    new_col = []
    i = 0
    for column in old_col:
        if (column in running_list):
            new_col.append(column + "_" + str(i))
            i = i + 1
        else:
            new_col.append(column)
            running_list.append(column)
    df_out = df.toDF(*new_col)
    return  df_out`

Comment: if column name is only number(this usually doesn't happen) replacing column by str(column) should do the job

Answer (score 0):

the easy way I am doing it is:

```
def col_duplicates(self):
    '''rename dataframe with dups'''
    columnas = self.columns.copy()
    for i in range(len(columnas)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(columnas), 1):
            if columnas[i] == columnas[j]:
                columnas[j] = columnas[i] + '_dup_' + str(j) # this line controls how to rename
    return self.toDF(*columnas)
```

use as:

```
new_df_without_duplicates = col_duplicates(df_with_duplicates)
```